# Using a Javascript variable in asp:textbox text parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to use a javascript variable (value handed over via the url) in the `asp:textbox` paramater text in order to have the field filled in:

```
<div id="username" class="form-group">
<label for="txtUsername">Email</label> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var username = querySt("username");
//document.write(username);
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" text="<%= username %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

The value is not shown. How to I get the value of the variable used in the `text` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

To get the value in JavaScript, you can read it from the element in the DOM.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" text="<%= username %>"></asp:TextBox>
<script>
    var username = document.getElementById('<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>').value;
    //document.write(username);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

assign the value to your textbox text like this

```
<script>
    var username = querySt("username");
    document.getElementById('<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>').value =username;
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still the value is not displayed in the field. When I uncomment the document.write, I can see that the variable is set.